# Converting STL List to a Binary Search Tree Recursion Template

Tags: c++, recursion, stl

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "bintree.h"
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace main_savitch_10;

template <class Item>
binary_tree_node<Item>* convert(list<Item> *& list, int start, int end);

template <class Item> 
binary_tree_node<Item>* convert(list<Item> *head, int n);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    list<int> L;
    L.push_front(10);
    L.push_back(20);
    L.push_back(30);
    L.push_back(40);
    L.push_back(50);
    L.push_back(60);
    L.push_back(70);
    list<int>::iterator test;
    for(test = L.begin(); test != L.end(); test++)
    {
    cout<<*test<<" ";
    }

    binary_tree_node<int>* L2 = convert(L, 7);

    print(L2, 3);

}

template <class Item>
binary_tree_node<Item>* convert(list<Item> *& list, int start, int end)
{
    if (start > end) return NULL;
    int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
    binary_tree_node<Item>* leftChild = convert(list, start, mid-1);
    binary_tree_node<Item>* parent = new binary_tree_node<Item> (list->data());
    parent->left() = leftChild;
    list = list->next();
    parent->right() = convert(list, mid+1, end);
    return parent;
}

template <class Item> 
binary_tree_node<Item>* convert(list<Item> *head, int n) 
{
    return convert(head, 0, n-1);
}
```

I am getting an error at line 
`binary_tree_node<int>* L2 = convert(L, 7);`

Saying that there is no matching function for the call... how is this possible when I have them listed right above the main?

Side note: the "bintree.h" and the namespace main_savitch_10 are from template implementation files of binary search tree and can be found at 
http://ksuweb.kennesaw.edu/~dgayler/cs3304/text_examples/chap10/bintree.h
http://ksuweb.kennesaw.edu/~dgayler/cs3304/text_examples/chap10/bintree.template

Comment: Do you know the difference between a pointer and everything that isn't a pointer?

Comment: I understand the basic concept behind a pointer yes, although sometimes I struggle to differentiate when to use them. Is there a certain line or several lines you are referring to in which they should not be used? @molbdnilo

Answer (score 0):

Your function takes a pointer to a list. That means that you should pass the address of your list to it.

Answer (score 0):

If I look af this:

```
template <class Item> 
binary_tree_node<Item>* convert(list<Item> *head, int n)
```

then at this:

```
binary_tree_node<int>* L2 = convert(L, 7);
```

and then at this:

```
list<int> L;
```

I might be wrong about it, but L is not a pointer, you don't use its addresse in the call and the definition wants a pointer.